# How to deploy the RESTlet script for all roles in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

Only owners are able to access NetSuite script record from UI.

Even though the owner sets deployment for all employees and all roles, not all employees are able to call the RESTlet.

for e.g.: Prasun and Prabhu are users, Prasun can edit or modify the script of Prabhu in GUI. But,Prasun can not access(execute) the script of Prabhu.

Comment: you mean to say even though the deployment is for all employees, not all employees are able to access the RESTlet script record in NetSuite?

Comment: Yes Prasun all employees and all roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the owner sets deployment for all employees and all roles, not all employees are able to call the RESTlet.

The only reason it should not be accessible can be script **Deployment Status** is in **Testing** and not **released**,  provided correct Auth headers are used and credentials are correct.